# C++: how to test if an instance of a class contains a given member in a template function?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

C++: how to test if an instance of a class contains a given member in a template function?

I googled this, looked over examples that are supposed to work... But still don't understand *why*?!...

The first thing I could have thought of is using traits and template specialization, seems this doesn't work.

Indeed, this is OK:

```
>> cat main.cpp 
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct point2D {
    double x = 0.;
    double y = 0.;
};

struct point3D {
    double x = 0.;
    double y = 0.;
    double z = 0.;
};

template <typename T> struct has_z : std::false_type {}; // default case.
template <> struct has_z<point3D> : std::true_type {}; // specialized case.

template<typename T> void print(T const & obj) {
  std::cout << obj.x << " " << obj.y;
  //if (has_z<T>::value) std::cout << obj.z;
  std::cout << std::endl;
};

int main() {
  point2D pt2D;
  print(pt2D);
  point3D pt3D;
  print(pt3D);
}

>> g++ -o main main.cpp
>> ./main 
0 0
0 0
```

But, uncommenting the commented line gives:

```
>> g++ -o main main.cpp 
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void print(const T&) [with T = point2D]’:
main.cpp:27:8:   required from here
main.cpp:21:41: error: ‘const struct point2D’ has no member named ‘z’
   21 |   if (has_z<T>::value) std::cout << obj.z;
      |                                     ~~~~^
```

What is the minimal change to get this to work (with C++20) and *why*?

Comment: Do you know what `if constexpr` is, how it works, and how to use it?

Comment: I know it's an `if` evaluated at compile time. Just tested replacing `if` with `if constexpr`: it works?!... Can you explain why and/or why my first thought was wrong?

Comment: For comparison: `int n; if(false) { n = std::string(); }` – fails, too, even though the branch obviously cannot ever be met. Standard requires evaluation of the entire code, the compiler only is allowed to *optimise* away afterwards...

Comment: Your well-researched, edited, and proofread C++ textbook will explain `if constexpr` far better than I can.

Comment: [OT]: `template <typename T> concept has_z = requires { T::z; };` seems more appropriate [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PdPT953M1), your version is `is_point3D`.

Comment: @Jarod42: you're right! Thanks for the illustrative example!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use:

```
template<typename T> void print(T const & obj) {
  std::cout << obj.x << " " << obj.y;

  if constexpr(has_z<T>::value) std::cout << obj.z;

  std::cout << std::endl;
};
```

That way, the compiler knows the expression is a compile-time constexpr and can remove the `.z` read. Otherwise, the `if` is runtime and the compiler can't generate one possibility (the read of `.z`, never mind it would never happen to run)